# How to refer to the strong named assembly from the App.config?

Tags: .net, assemblies, reference, strongname

We have many assemblies which used to be private assemblies referenced from `\bin` folder. I have added `configSection` in the App.config file which refer to the assembly from `\bin` folder.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Logger" type="Logger.Client.Reader,Logger.Client,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null"/>
</configSections>
```

Now we have decided to strong name the assemblies. We did so. 
Now when I reference the assembly in above `configSection`, do I need to have all the details like `version` and the `PublicKeyToken` ? At present, I have not added assmblies to GAC and they are still under \bin folder.

When it's mandatory to provide all the details as seen above? And when (and which) it can be excluded?

Comment: ASP.NET, right? Then why App.config, when you should use Web.config?

Comment: I have winform application. So it's app.config. And I have same configuration in web.config for the web services too.

Comment: @abatishchev: whether you have areference in the project or not is irrelevant to this question. You need to specify the assemblyname so that the system.configuration subsystem can load/find it.

Comment: sure, sorry, misread. config section declaration, i see

Comment: the easiest way you can do: try both ways - take strong-named assembly and specify it with and w/out FQN, and you will see. From my experience, it will work, because you can use FCL assemblies w/o FQN, e.g. just "System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection, System.Configuration"

Comment: Please refer to the accepted answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807420/adding-assembly-reference-within-web-config. Yes, for a short answer, you need to mention the culture and public key token for referring the strong named assembly.

Answer (score 1):

See MSDN articles: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx).

> A strong-named assembly has a fully qualified name that includes the assembly's name, culture, public key, and version number. This is frequently referred to as the display name, and **for loaded assemblies can be obtained by using the FullName property.**

See [`Assembly.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname.aspx).

Comment: +1 This has cleared most of the points. The post you have referred to says that `All assembly references to assemblies that make up the .NET Framework also must contain a fully qualified name of the assembly. ` And I understand that it must be true for my own strong named assemblies too. But do you know whether non-.NET assemblies too need to have Fully Qualified names while referencing them from the config files as I showed ?