# Recently installed package can't be referenced

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

Installed Rotativa (https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/README.md) with NPM. I restarted VS. Then I tried updating with:

```
Update-Package -reinstall Rotativa
```

And I'm still getting a "The type or namespace Rotativa could not be found" error on the using statement.

I can confirm that the Rotativa folder is in my solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does web.config has a reference to this dll and its same version to what you have in you packages.config.. They also have a newer version for Asp Net Core..

Comment: @numbtongue No, nothing in web.config. Is that required? If so, tips on adding? (need public key token)

Comment: May be If you copy it From packages.config to web.config like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40368267/3254405

Comment: It doesn't seem that way, since packages.config doesn't have a PublicKeyToken. @numbtongue

Comment: Under references folder in VS check if the file listed without any warning icon, and verify the same version to packages by right click properties.. Otherwise try removing it and add it back by browsing to its folder..

Comment: To get public key you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948633/3254405