# What is the reason behind <assemblies> tag in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I am currently working on a web site and have just came across a missing assembly reference  problem, which made me come up with this question:

Is not it true to say that all the needed assemblies in configuration/system.web/compilation/assemblies tag already exist in related asp project dll
file? So there would not be a need to put all of these references into another place(i.e. assemblies tag) as this dll will be put on the server at the time of deployment(Am I wrong with this?)

I don't have much experience in asp.net. I think my question should be somehow 
related to the web site deployment concepts and my lack of knowledge of how it works.

I have googled my question in hope of finding some useful reference, but nothing found.

I have already seen this tag
[What is difference between web.config assemblies element and project file Reference element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818188/what-is-difference-between-web-config-assemblies-element-and-project-file-refere)
but it wasn't useful for me.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a suitable answer, the tag is only needed when you want to have .cs code on the server for the on-the-fly compilation purposes, if precompilation mode are being used, as I have currently used it, the tag contents won't be needed.