# Why do we add dll in the web.config

Tags: asp.net, dll, web-config

What is the advantage of add assembly in the **web.config**

```
add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

aganist adding assembly to the reference

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Different tags have different meanings. You should paste more to reveal which configuration section it is. Many of them instruct ASP.NET runtime to load extensions (modules/handlers), but not all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between web.config assemblies element and project file Reference element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818188/what-is-difference-between-web-config-assemblies-element-and-project-file-refere)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a previous Stack Overflow question answering this (Web site vs Web App):

[What is difference between web.config assemblies element and project file Reference element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619268/4324451)