# Difference in referencing an assembly in web.config and project reference root?

Tags: c#

I am building this project and i have an external dll . I want to add a reference to it from the root reference folder . I have not tried though if its wrong.
But there is an obvious answer to this question across internet stating i have to referenc e the dll in the web.config assembly file .

I want to know why do we need to do so?

what is the differences between both ways ?

Answer (score -1):

in the web.config section

> The assemblies element defines a collection of assembly names that are
>   used during compilation of an ASP.NET application.

The assemblies element us usually used in web site projects as there is no project file storing location of references that the web site uses. The project references would not apply to a web site, as it has no proper project file to store these in, so must store all referenced assemblies in the web.config. There is some interesting, although not directly related, discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144612/where-are-web-application-project-assembly-references-stored). In a web application project you can use both the assemblies element and project references.

Having a reference in the assemblies element also means you won't have to add the @register at the top of any .aspx pages that use that namespace. More discussion on that [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/753705.aspx).

Comment: Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818335/525558